# Invoke a function with is faster than directly invoking?

Tags: javascript

I tested performance with a script from "Secrets of Javascript Ninja":

```js
function isPrime(number) {
  if (number < 2) {
    return false;
  }
  for (let i = 2; i < number; i++) {
    if (number % i === 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

console.time("isPrime");
isPrime(1299827);
console.timeEnd("isPrime");

console.time("isPrime");
isPrime.apply(1299827);
console.timeEnd("isPrime");
```

And the result is:

```
isPrime: 8.276ms
isPrime: 0.779ms
```

Seems that "apply" is faster?

Comment: They don't do the same thing.

Comment: to demonstrate how your code is wrong, try `console.log(isPrime.apply(1299826));` ... note: no matter what argument you supply - even, say a string, like `'purple dinosaur'` - the result is always `true`

Comment: @JaromandaX what does Barney have to do with it? xD

Answer (score 5):

Your comparison is not accurate, because the first parameter passed to `apply` is the `this` value of the called function, and the second parameter passed to `apply` is an array of parameters that function is to be called with. So, your `apply` is not calling `isPrime` with any parameters, so no iterations run, because the condition `i < number` is not fulfilled when `i` is 2 and `number` is `undefined`:

```js
function isPrime(number) {
  console.log('calling with ' + number);
  if (number < 2) {
    return false;
  }
  for (let i = 2; i < number; i++) {
    if (number % i === 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

console.time("isPrime");
isPrime(1299827);
console.timeEnd("isPrime");

console.time("isPrime");
isPrime.apply(1299827);
console.timeEnd("isPrime");
```

If you use `apply` properly and pass in `undefined, [1299827]`, the result is as expected, very similar. You should also use `performance.now()` for better precision than `console` at the millisecond level, though for such a quick operation you might not see that might difference anyway:

```js
function isPrime(number){
    console.log('calling with ' + number);
    if(number < 2) { return false; }
    for(let i = 2; i < number; i++) {
        if(number % i === 0) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
}

const t1 = performance.now();
isPrime(1299827);
const t2 = performance.now();

isPrime.apply(undefined, [1299827]);
console.timeEnd("isPrime");
const t3 = performance.now();
console.log(t2 - t1);
console.log(t3 - t2);
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for .apply is

> function.apply(thisArg, [argsArray])

the first parameter thisArg refers to the value of 'this' when calling the function, in your case isPrime.apply(1299827) you passed in 1299827 as 'this' but no parameter, so it's really isPrime(), the for loop is not excuted so it's faster
more on .apply here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score 2):

You have to read this.

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

This point is `Array.prototype.apply(context = this, args = [])`, so your code is wrong.

Change your code to this.

```
// incorrect.
isPrime.apply(1299827);
// correct.
isPrime.apply(this, 1299827);
```